# How can I identify the time after user update?

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

How can I identify the time passed after an user updated his account in my MySQL database? I have a timestamp in my MySQL table (to store user update time) so now how can I identify the time passed from last user update, using PHP?

As example:

> User last update time: 2012-04-08 00:20:00;
>
> Now: 2012-04-08 00:40:00;
>
> Time passed since last update: 20  (minutes) ← I need this using PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the data on

```
$last_update_time = '2012-04-08 00:20:00';
$now = time(); //this gets you the seconds since epoch
```

you can do

```
$last_update_since_epoch = strtotime($last_update_time); //this converts the string to the seconds since epoch
```

aand... now, since you have seconds on both variables

```
$seconds_passed = $now - $last_update_since_epoch;
```

now, you can do `$seconds_passed / 60` to get the minutes passed since the last update.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code:

```
$get_user_time = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp FROM table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($get_user_time);
$user_time = $row['timestamp'];  //This is the last update time for the user

$now_unformatted = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$now = date("m/d/y g:i A", $now_unformatted); // This is the current time

$difference = $now->diff($user_time); // This is the difference

echo $difference;
```

[diff()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) is supported in >= PHP 5.3. Otherwise you could do:

```
$difference = time() - $user_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$secs=time()-strtotime($timestamp);
```

would give u number of seconds before it was updated and then you can convert this seconds into your needed time format like 
`echo $secs/60." minutes ago";`

Answer (score 0):

why not do it with mysql:

```
select TIMEDIFF(NOW(),db_timestamp) as time_past
```